# Completely Remove MySQL Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lts

I somehow have messed up my MySQL on my Ubuntu server and cannot fix it. I have tried every single combination of `apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get purge`, Googled for hours and nothing.

I have literally given up. Every time I try to reinstall I get error. I've had enough. I want to remove every single file associated with MySQL on my server.

I get this error every time I try to reinstall which seems to be common but not one "fix" has worked for me. I need to clean my system of everything MySQL.

```
Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                                                                                                        
An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or   
because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.                                                                                               
You should check the account's password after the package installation.                                                                                 
Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.
```

Please can someone give me a set of command to purge this ungodly database from my system before I do a fresh install of the server.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
140811 10:56:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have literally tried everything. Every single `mysql` file is removed and it still will not install properly.

Comment: Can you please accept one of the answers to your question?

Answer (score 94):

To completly remove Mysql from Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

after this, if you are having issues with re installing, Try to remove Mysql files in :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Did all of that. Still have an error. What is even more weird is if I do a find / -name "mysql" /var/lib/mysql still appears but if I try to navigate to that directory it doesn't exist....

Comment: Remove /etc/my.cnf file and retry the installation, it worked for me for exactly same problem. :-)
I hope it will help someone else.

Comment: I was able to reinstall corrupted Mysql as instructed above. I didn't have to remove any files from /var/lib/mysql. When the remove script asked about deleting the underlying phpMyAdmin database, I answered no. Then I reinstalled mysql-server. Afterward when reinstalling phpMyAdmin when the script asked about creating the phpMyAdmin database, I answered no, as would be logical. After reboot, everything was intact. I had dumped all the databases, just in case.

Comment: While uninstalling I encountered a few errors with folders not being empty. I had to use `rm -R troublesome/folder` to delete them. Afterwards I could reinstall mysql.

Comment: @ExploringApple The folder I needed to delete was /etc/mysql/ rather than the file /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 40):

I experienced a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after a MySQL update.

I started getting error: "Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'" in /var/log/mysql/error.log

MySQL could not start.

I resolved it by removing the following directory: /var/lib/mysql/mysql

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql
```

This leaves your other DB related files in place, only removing the mysql related files.

After running these:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then reinstalling mysql:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Different solution for those still having issues.  Hopefully I  can help those trying to reinstall Mysql.  Note, It's a seek and destroy mission.  So be weary.  Assuming your root:

```
apt-get purge mysql*
apt-get purge dbconfig-common #the screen used for mysql password
find / -name *mysql*          #delete any traces of mysql
#insert apt-get cleanups, autoremove,updates etc.
```

Originally, something leftover was interfering with my startup of mysqlserver-5.5.  These commands ended up resolving the issue for myself.

Comment: - Good procedure - Some ` sys ` files are not removed, but no impact for new installation. Before removing, take care if some *mysql* repertories contains your saved files !

Answer (score 4):

The following works:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I had to remove all the package listed by `dpkg -l | grep mysql` to completely uninstall mysql

Answer (score 2):

**Use apt to uninstall and remove all MySQL packages:**

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**Remove the MySQL folder:**

```
 $ rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

**Delete all MySQL files on your server:**

```
$ sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

**Your system should no longer contain default MySQL related files.**

Answer (score 1):

**sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql***

Remove the MySQL packages fully from the target system.

**sudo apt-get purge mysql***

Remove all mysql related configuration files.

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

Clean up unused dependencies using autoremove command.

**sudo apt-get autoclean**

To clear all local repository in the target system.

**sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql**

If you also want to delete your local/config files for dbconfig-mysql then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what saved me. Apparently the depackager tries to put things in the wrong tmp folder.

https://askubuntu.com/a/248860

Answer (score 0):

Remove /etc/my.cnf file and retry the installation, it worked for me for exactly same problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

remove mysql :

```
sudo apt -y purge mysql*
sudo apt -y autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
```

Restart instance :

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had this same issue.  It turns out for me, mysql was already installed and working.  I just didn't know how to check.

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
```

This will show you if mysql is already running.  If it is it should return something like this:

```
mysql    24294  0.1  1.3 550012 52784 ?        Ssl  15:16   0:06        /usr/sbin/mysqld
gwang    27451  0.0  0.0  15940   924 pts/3    S+   16:34   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```