# MySql Install on Ubuntu root issue

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Setting.  I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on a custom machine with an existing PHP / Apache / Sqlite setup.  I recently installed MySql to fiddle around with Laravel a bit.  It was working perfectly until I wasn't paying attention and did something incredibly stupid.  I intended to export all of the user's privileges to a new database, was in a hurry, and instead clicked the button to dump all users.  So, yeah.  Complete dumped every user in MySql, including root.  Obviously I was unable to log back in with PhpMyAdmin, because no root user.  Since this was just a testing install I went ahead and purged MySql and re-installed, thinking it would just go through the install process again.  NOPE.  I've uninstalled / reinstalled using the terminal, synatpic, and Ubuntu Software Center.  In each case the install of MySql client server just breezes through without even asking for a root user.  I can't even check status to see if the server is running without getting an unauthorized error.  I would really like to get this fixed, but without uninstalling apache2 and php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After yet another purge / install cycle I have mysql mostly working again.  I can log in as root from the command line, and I am able to log in via PhpMyAdmin, for the most part.  Unfortunately, while I seem to still have all of the necessary PhpMyAdmin functionality the page itself throws several iterations of the following error:

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I've researched this error and none of the conditions that are said to cause it exist in my system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28113482/4621324

Answer (score 2):

First try this.

```
mysql -u root -p password
```

if first method does not work then use following method to reset your MySQL password.

1. Check your version of the MySQL database.

   apt-cache policy mysql-server
2. Start configuration setting of the MySQL database.

   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-** . **

   **"replace ** . ** with your MySQL database version"**

It will open a configuration prompt where you will can change password.

If both of the above methods fails then use this method as last resort.

1. Stop your MySQL database server

   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. Start demon process without grant table.

   sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
3. Start MySQL and flush the privilige.

   mysql -u root

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4. Now set the password for the root user.

   USE mysql

   UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')

   WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND User = 'root';