# Cannot get mysql to start with --skip-grant-tables on ubuntu 16

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I lost my mysql password and need to reset it. 
I have already tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

With the following result

```
erik@Trantor:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
erik@Trantor:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 21335
erik@Trantor:~$ 
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
erik@Trantor:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
erik@Trantor:~$
```

I did not use the skip-networking option as that has been indicated by another post to cause it's own trouble and I'm not worried about security at the moment. Through some checking, I found that the service is failing to actually start with that option.

```
erik@Trantor:~$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2016-11-06 10:41:56 EST; 3min 45s ago
  Process: 20846 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=e
  Process: 20845 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20842 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 20845 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 06 10:35:01 Trantor systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 06 10:35:02 Trantor systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 06 10:41:55 Trantor systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Nov 06 10:41:56 Trantor systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

I'm not sure how to get mysql to start with the -skip-grant-tables option at this point, and without my password, I'm dead in the water.

I have tried to remove and install mysql-server again.

Anyone know how I can get it to start with the flag, or where I should look next?

Comment: I tried to do a complete removal and reinstall using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244606/completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-14-04-lts but it never asked me to enter a password like it should if it was a first install.

In the end I remembered my password. But would still love to know why this wasn't working since I may find it happens again.